# Python packaging with data directories - Clean uninstall

Tags: python, installation, pip, uninstallation, python-packaging

I am writing a Python package that relies on some expensive to generate and large data file in order to properly work.

This large file only needs to be generated once, so I have configured the package's `__init__.py` to generate this file upon import. This file could also be generated at any other point (as soon as it's needed). The point is that this file is not part of the package as it would be too large to distribute.

The file is saved into the package directory, using code such as:

```
data_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "data")
# save file to directory
```

which would point to some directory such as: `/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/my-package/lib/python3.11/site-packages/my_package`. It's assumed the user has write permission to the python package directory (should be using a virtual environment).

I want users to be able to install and uninstall the package using pip. The data files should be deleted on uninstall since they take too much space.

Even though the data files are inside the package directory (this directly gets removed in a regular uninstall), pip is raising a warning about files inside the package directory not belonging to the package and it will not remove it.

```
❯ pip uninstall my-package
Found existing installation: my_package 0.0.1
Uninstalling my_package-0.0.1:
Would remove:
/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/my-package/lib/python3.11/site-packages/my_package-0.0.1.dist-info/*
/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/my-package/lib/python3.11/site-packages/my_package/*
Would not remove (might be manually added):
/Users/me/anaconda3/envs/my-package/lib/python3.11/site-packages/my_package/data/file
Proceed (Y/n)?
```

After running the uninstall will remove all files expect these manually added files.

I guess this could be solved by marking these files as not manually added, so pip knows it can remove them, but I don't know if this is possible. Another solution would be to automatically run some script just-before or after uninstall.

I could not find any satisfactory solution to this problem online so I am probably missing something, what is the established solution for this problem? Is this achievable by modifying the `pyproject.toml` file?

Comment: Read the note in this [section of the Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/recording-installed-packages/#the-record-file) "It is strongly discouraged for an installed package to modify itself (e.g., store cache files under its namespace in site-packages). Changes inside site-packages should be left to specialized installer tools such as pip. If a package is nevertheless modified in this way, then the RECORD must be updated, otherwise uninstalling the package will leave unlisted files in place (possibly resulting in a zombie namespace package)."

Comment: Related discussion: https://github.com/pypa/packaging.python.org/pull/1423

Comment: Thanks, the links are really useful. Now I know how I could do it and why I shouldn't do it (I already suspected that, given how little information was available online).

One questions remains: What is the alternative? I can imagine this is not that uncommon. Installing files in a arbitrary user directory and just leaving them there for the user to manually remove? Using the temporary directory and having to repeteadly regenerate the files everytime it's cleared? My choice would be to automatically run some python code after `pip uninstall`, but there isn't a way to do this right?

Comment: If you are serious about this, implement this well, and do not abuse it, then there is no reason to not do what is suggested in the links I shared. -- Typically I recommend writing this kind of data into one of the directories pointed at by [*platformdirs*](https://pypi.org/project/platformdirs/), but yes the issue is that they do not get deleted automatically.